# opencv area of contour

Tags: opencv, contour

I am trying to find the contours of an animal from a picture. Let's assume it is a chicken. From the picture I could find its contours but they aren't closed. Also, I am getting a lot of noise from the background which is white ( same as the chicken).
I am using a simple code found on stackoverflow.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('lateral.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (5, 5), 0)
# edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 10, 11) # 10 and 40 to be more perceptive
# contours_canny= cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
edges = cv2.Canny(imgray, 10,30)    

cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
k = cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: The result is this one.]

[image: This is the original Image]

Is there a way to find just the contour of this chicken?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick check in Photoshop Express: if you pump the saturation maximum, chicken tints yellow while the wall and floor to blueish or neutral. So pump saturation channel and use grabCut. For this particular case that is.

Comment: Do you need to do it to this exact photo?

Answer (score 0):

Finding contour is quite easy. The problem is that your image has low contrast between the chicken and the background. So, your idea of using canny edges was not bad, it just needed some post processing.

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread("./chicken.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
image = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5) 


imgray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)[...,0]
edges = cv2.Canny(imgray, 10,30)    
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(edges, (9, 9), 0)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=5.0, tileGridSize=(32,32))
contrast = clahe.apply(blurred)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(contrast, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

maxArea = 0
best = None
for contour in contours:
  area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
  print (area)
  if area > maxArea :

    maxArea = area
    best = contour


cv2.drawContours(image, [best], 0, (0, 0, 255), -1)

while True:
  cv2.imshow("result", image)
  k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
  if k == 27:
      break
```

[image]